# Diagonal lemma from recursion theorem?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

Does Gödel's diagonal lemma follow from Kleene's recursion theorem? I believe the converse is true, by an argument like the following.

Let e ↦ θ<sub>e</sub> be a bijection between ω and the set of Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>1</sub> formulas in the language of arithmetic having just the variable v<sub>0</sub> free.

Let e ↦ W<sub>e</sub> be a numbering of the r.e. subsets of ω such that for all e, W<sub>e</sub> = {n ∈ ω : θ<sub>e</sub>(n) is true}. This is possible because every r.e. set is defined in the standard model of arithmetic by a Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>1</sub> formula.

Let f be any recursive operation on ω. To prove the recursion theorem, we seek a number d such that W<sub>d</sub> = W<sub>f(d)</sub>.

Toward that, let φ(v<sub>0</sub>, v<sub>1</sub>) be a Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>1</sub> formula satisfied by a pair (n, e) iff θ<sub>f(e)</sub>(n) is true. For instance, φ might be

> Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>1</sub>-Tr[ Sub(numeral(v<sub>0</sub>), 0, f(v<sub>1</sub>)) ]

so that φ(n, e) says that a true Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>1</sub> sentence results from substituting the numeral for n into the formula with code f(e).

By the diagonal lemma, there is a Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>1</sub> formula θ<sub>d</sub>(v<sub>0</sub>) such that

> ∀v<sub>0</sub>[ θ<sub>d</sub>(v<sub>0</sub>) ↔ φ(v<sub>0</sub>, d) ]

is provable in Robinson's arithmetic. Hence

> W<sub>d</sub> = {n ∈ ω : θ<sub>d</sub>(n) is true} = {n ∈ ω : φ(n,d) is true} = {n ∈ ω : θ<sub>f(d)</sub>(n) is true} = W<sub>f(d)</sub>

as desired. The second equality follows by choice of θ<sub>d</sub>.

My question is whether we can prove the diagonal lemma from the recursion theorem. For specificity, here is the lemma I have in mind:

> For any formula φ(v<sub>0</sub>, v<sub>1</sub>, … v<sub>n</sub>) in the language of arithmetic, one can find a formula ψ(v<sub>1</sub>, … v<sub>n</sub>) in that language, so that Robinson's arithmetic proves ∀φv<sub>1</sub>…∀φv<sub>n</sub>[ ψ(v<sub>1</sub>, … v<sub>n</sub>) ↔ φ(⌜ψ⌝, v<sub>1</sub>, … v<sub>n</sub>) ].

Note that it is not sufficient to prove that for each φ there is a ψ for which the stated equivalence holds; the equivalence must be provable in Robinson's arithmetic.

Comment: You may have already seen this, but in section 5 of the paper below, the "one-formula-at-a-time" version of the Diagonal Lemma is derived from Kleene's (Second) Recursion Theorem:

*Kleene's amazing Second Recursion Theorem*, by Yiannis N. Moschovakis, **Bulletin of Symbolic Logic**, June 2010, pages 189 — 239, an online copy of which is available at http://www.math.ucla.edu/~asl/bsl/1602-toc.htm



Comment: Thanks, Ali. I was unaware of that paper, and will take a look.