# Does Robinson Arithmetic already entail the Recursion Theorem?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

Gödel's incompleteness theorem already holds for $Q$ (Robinson's Arithmetic), by design. Is $Q$ already strong enough to support (entail) Kleene's recursion theorem, or are there some limits to recursion at this level?

Comment: What do you mean by "support Kleene's recursion theorem"? Are you asking whether the recursion theorem is provable in Q?

Comment: Yes, it is the latter. My question is in part motivated by coming to clarity as to whether Edvard Nelson's finitism (as witnessed e.g. in his eminent https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nelson/books/pa.pdf) and arithmetical skepticism have roots in considerations upon the recursion theorem.

Comment: For this question to have a definite answer, you'd need to specify the exact formalization of the recursion theorem that you have in mind.  Formalizations that are trivially equivalent might not be provably equivalent in Q, because Q is so weak. For example, although Q (the version I'm accustomed to) proves $(\forall x)(x+0=x)$, it doesn't prove $(\forall x)(0+x=x)$, so if you had asked "Does Q prove that 0 is an additive identity?" the answer would depend on whether you meant left, right, or 2-sided identity. With a statement as complex as the recursion theorem, [continued in next comment]

Comment: [continuation of previous comment] the issue becomes much bigger. I'd expect that, if you were to formalize the recursion theorem explicitly, it would most probably not be provable in Q, unless you designed your formalization very cleverly in order to make it provable.

Comment: @Andreas Blass Many thanks for this! I would have liked it if there were informative weaknesses of Kleene's recursion theorem and that Rogers' fixed point theorem did not hold generally in $Q$, but that is just a statement of preferences. Incidentally, from what I have come to understand Gödel's incompleteness theorem follows from the Kleene recursion theorem.

Comment: @Andreas Blass I take your expectation to somehow almost accord with the preference I just stated.

Comment: A more direct proof of Gödel's incompleteness theorem uses Gödel's diagonal lemma instead of Kleene's recursion theorem. The former *does* hold for Q.

Comment: Also, you mention Nelson’s finitism. Well, for Nelson, $Q$ is the starting point, but he would not actually expect interesting things to be directly provable in $Q$ (hardly anything is). What he did was to construct a theory, IIRC denoted $Q^*$, which is interpretable in $Q$ on a cut, and prove stuff in $Q^*$. The theory includes e.g. $I\Delta_0+\Omega_1$. The recursion theorem *is* provable in such a theory, under a reasonable enumeration of algorithms.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Many thanks! Could there be "unreasonable" enumerations of algorithms in a system as $I\Delta_0+\Omega_1$ so that one had Kleene Normal Form but not the recursion theorem?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek The use of the Diagonal Lemma seems to be the standard in deriving incompleteness nowadays. In the following question the OP puts forward an alleged derivation of the Recursion Theorem from the Diagonal Lemma. Does this show that the recursion theorem already holds at $Q$?

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70461/diagonal-lemma-from-recursion-theorem

Comment: For the record, I am not convinced that the alleged derivation of the Recursion Theorem from theDiagonal Lemma in the link I posted to in my previous comment is valid.

Comment: The derivation may well be correct (I didn’t check the details), but it is not carried out in Robinson’s arithmetic. It would need a much stronger theory.